# $A$ is c.e. $ \Leftrightarrow$ $A \le_{1}K_{0}$

Tags: logic

$A$ is c.e. $ \Leftrightarrow$ $A \le_{1}K_{0}$

let $A\subseteq N$ show that if $A$ is c.e. $ \Leftrightarrow$  $A \le_{1}K_{0}$
proof:$\Leftarrow$

$A \le_{1}K_{0}$ via$f $  then we have 
$ x\in A \Leftrightarrow \ f(x) \in K_{0}=\{<x,e>: x\in W_{e}\}$and

$x\in A \Leftrightarrow x\in W_{e}\Leftrightarrow (\exists s) x\in W_{e,s}\Rightarrow x\in \sum_{1}^{0}\Rightarrow A\in\sum_{1}^{0} $ by normal form theorem $A$ is c.e.

for $\Rightarrow$

$x\in A \rightarrow x\in W_{e}\Leftrightarrow <x,e>\in K_{0} $ so  $A \le_{1}K_{0}$  via $x\rightarrow <x,e>$
 could i tell $f:x\rightarrow <x,e>$ is one-one?how?

Answer (score 0):

As you predicted, for a fixed index $e$, the function $f :x \mapsto \langle x, e \rangle$ is one-one, i.e., injective.  Why?  Because you should have defined the pairing function $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle : \omega \times \omega \rightarrow \omega$ to be injective (so that $\langle a,b \rangle = \langle x,y \rangle$ implies $a=x$ and $b=y$)!  You may want to check this with your definition of the pairing.

Comment: The argument for the former part is somewhat unclear, though.

Comment: Also, please consider accepting this answer (not just upvoting it) if you find it useful.